# Solving a diffusion equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I need to solve the diffusion equation on the positive half-line and I don't really have clue on how to do this question. I've looked at other examples and seem to understand those but haven't been given any examples like this.

$\frac{∂u}{∂t} - D \frac{∂^2u}{∂x^2} = 0, x∈[0,∞], t∈[0,∞]   $

subject to the condition

$u(x,0) = Qδ(x − x_0),  u_x(0, t) = 0$.

Where $Q\neq 0$ and $x_0 > 0$ are given constants, and δ(·) is the Dirac delta-function.

With the hint: Consider an even extension

Comment: Half line typically means Laplace Transform in the x variable, solve the resulting ordinary differential equation in the t variable and go from there.

Answer (score 0):

The boundary condition $u_x(0,t)=0$ suggests to extend the solution to the full upper half plane in such a way that it is even, that is, $u(x,t)=u(-x,t)$. Then you obtain the equation
$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} - D\,\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2} = 0,\quad x\in(-\infty,\infty),\quad t\ge0.
$$
The initial value will be $u(x,0)=Q\,\delta(x-x_0)+Q\,\delta(x+x_0)$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: After this do I need to use the Fourier integral as I have seen in other questions? If so how to i get the values to put into the formula? Thanks.

Comment: Taking the Fourier transform is a possibility. Another one is to use the formula for the solution in terms of the heat kernel.